# How to remove obsolete database columns in SilverStripe

Tags: php, mysql, silverstripe

Is there a convenient way to remove obsolete **table columns** from the database? I'm wondering if there is a more convention-based solutions rather than logging into PHPMyADMIN and deleting columns manually.

**Example**
When installing SilverStripe-Fluent and adding an extra locale (eg nz-NZ) the module will split each SiteTree record to add extra translation columns with prefix `_nz-NZ`. Suppose we delete the extra locale (nz-NZ), the columns will stay there after a /dev/build.

Comment: I don't know a solution for fluent but you could write a task to do so. See the Tasks already in Fluent:

 [fluent-tasks](https://github.com/tractorcow/silverstripe-fluent/tree/master/code/tasks)

Here two related Modules to the subject:

 [silverstripe-version-truncator](https://github.com/axllent/silverstripe-version-truncator)
 [silverstripe-artefactcleaner](https://github.com/oddnoc/silverstripe-artefactcleaner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there was a great module [DBPlumber](https://github.com/smindel/silverstripe-dbplumber) for version 2.4 that had this function but I'm guessing you are using a later version!  It would be great if this was upgraded for V3.

The module [artefact cleaner](https://github.com/oddnoc/silverstripe-artefactcleaner) would be ideal.  Its description from the github page is...

> Find and optionally delete disused tables and fields in a SilverStripe
>   database.
>
> During development of a SilverStripe application it is common to
>   delete a data object class or remove a field from a data object. This
>   leaves obsolete columns and tables in your database. Because these
>   columns or tables may contain data that you still want, the
>   SilverStripe framework doesn't delete those automatically. This task
>   displays the obsolete columns and tables in the form of SQL DROP and
>   ALTER commands. It also provides a way to delete them. If you do that,
>   there is no undo, so always make a backup first.